How to send push notification using FCM HTTP v1 api on web application
I have an react web app. I want to implement Push Notification functionality in it. Since Firebase has migrated from legacy to HTTP v1. I want to know how to implement http v1 api to send web push notification.Since http v1 require oauth access token so how should I achieve this to send notification.
Do I need to create an api for generating oauth access token ?
I have created an react web app. Provide me with the steps to implement push notification (FCM HTTP V1) in it.

There is no secure way to send a message through Firebase Cloud Messaging directly from one client to another, neither through the legacy API nor through the v1 API.

Sending a message to other devices to show a notification can only be done from a trusted environment, such as the Firebase console, your development machine, a server that you control, or something like Cloud Functions/Cloud Run.
